# cannot create a folder under /mnt with root access rhel5.4

Tags: linux, rhel5

I'm not able to create a folder under `/mnt`

```
error: mkdir: Cannot create directory 'test': No such file or directory
```

I'm logged in as root: as file permissions :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 mnt
```

Comment: Could you post output from "mount; ls -la /mnt". Thx.

Comment: hi imo!

[root@station1 /]# mount; ls -la /mnt 
/dev/hda2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/hda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Apr  1 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Apr  1 11:16 ..
[root@station1 /]# 



regards
Simboy

Comment: You might move that to the body of your question for readability.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to figure out what the issue was.
I was playing with `autofs` and had an entry on `auto.master` for `/mnt` and I forgot about it!